# Running android virtual device along with a virtual box machine parallely

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I am a beginner in software engineering and have taken up Android as my programming choice. I wrote a simple Hello World app in Android and was able to run it successfully on the Android Virtual Device. Following is my working environment :-

1. Mac OS X
2. Android Studio version 1.5
3. Android Virtual Device - (bundled with Android Studio).

I also wanted to get acquainted with linux so I installed Virtual Box with ubuntu linux. This has now caused a weird issues on my development environment.
Whenever I have the ubuntu linux virtual machine running the Android Virtual Device does not start up. I get this error in Android Studio :-

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Ouput:
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context.
```

I just wanted to know if I am doing something wrong with the settings of the virtual box or Android Studio. If yes, is there a way to run both the AVD and another virtual machine on the same machine ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,